# Find the missing number in grid

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

When I doing the IQ paper last Sunday, I found an interesting question. Using that I made a different puzzle.

[image]

Hint 01:

> Middle number of each row build using the number before and
>  after it. Eg: 13 built using 25 & 43.

Hint 02:

> 4th row will be 55 73 73 & 5th row will be 65 36 83

Hint 03:

> If the 1st and last number of any row include the same letters with opposite like
>  35 and 53 (3 & 5 letters are in both), a middle number will have
>  definitely same letters like 66 (11,22,33, etc)

Hint 04:

> I had done a mistake when writing last hint(last row of the grid.). I
>  am really sorry about that, but you can get another hint from how I
>  correct my mistake. I mean which numbers I have changed to correct my
>  mistake... I will write the correct answer tomorrow.

---

Text version:

```
25 13 43
35 66 53
45 -- 63
55 73 73
65 36 83
```

Comment: Regarding your hint - my answer uses just that.

Comment: @rhsquared Replied it to... And I added another hint

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo in the hint 2?

Comment: It is sure... There is no typo in hint 2. I will give one more hint for you... If the 1st and last number include the same letters with opposite like 35 and 53 (3 & 5 letters are in both), a middle number will have definitely same letters like 66 (or 11,22,33, etc).

Comment: what would line 6 look like?

Comment: Are the rows set or are you making them up? 66 is an odd outlier in row 5!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first line:

> 2 * 5 = 10, 1 + 0 = 1 gives the first digit of the middle number
>  4 * 3 = 12, 1 + 2 = 3 gives the second digit of the middle number

This rule works for all, so the answer is:

> 4 * 5 = 20, 2 + 0 = 2
>  6 * 3 = 18, 1 + 8 = 9
>  29.

Comment: I think this is your first answer to this site. It is correct. Good work !!!!

Answer (score 0):

> If we name the columns  $A, B, C$ we can do the following:
>  $ABS((A1 + C1)/2 - B1) = ABS((25+43)/2 - 13) = 21$
>  $ABS((A2 + C2)/2 - B2) = ABS((35+53)/2 - 66) = ABS(-22) = 22$
>  Thus we can conclude that $ABS((A3 + C3)/2 - B3) = 23, or ABS(54 - B3) = 23$ and therefore
>  $B2$ could be either **31** or **77**

Comment: rot13 fbzrubj rneyvre v tbg 31 gbb ohg abg fher gb rkcynva vg

Comment: This is a good try, but there is a more accurate answer... I mean, your answers is x or y... However, this is a relly nice answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Possibly

> 31? As first row is -12 then +30, second is +31 then -13, so perhaps alternating and increasing both by 1 to give -14 then +32

Answer (score 0):

> 119

Because:

> The sum of the Row 1 value plus the Row 3 value divided by two equals the Row 2 value in each column.  SO: A1(25) + A3(45) /2 = (A2) 35 AND C1(43) + C3(63) /2 = (C2)53 Therefore B1(13) + B3(**119**) /2 = 66

Comment: I didn't take account of the hints. My answer is still wrong, despite the edits. :(

Answer (score -2):

> 33 is the answer I guess..is it crrct??

Comment: please provide complete reason for your answer

Comment: @user56231 Please provide reasoning as to why do you think this is the answer. Answers like this tend to get down votes. Also you need to hide your answer in a spoiler.